# Handling Arithmetic Right Shifts in ObjectPascal

Tags: c++, bit-shift, delphi

In translating some DSP C++ code to ObjectPascal, I am seeing a quite a few ">>" operators on signed integers (the right operand always being 1 or 2).  I know that on signed integers C++ performs an arithmetic right shift as opposed to a logical right shift in Pascal.

Currently I am substituting a 'div 2' or 'div 4' command for these ASR shifts. Is there a better, or more general, way to handle these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming that the left operand is a 32-bit variable:

```
(x>>1)|0x80000000

(x>>2)|0xC0000000
```

And if you want the general case for `x>>N`:

```
(x>>N)|(((1<<N)-1)<<(32-N))
```

Comment: I see, staying with bit operations, just mask to retain the sign. So in OP that would be `(x SHR 1) OR 0x80000000`. Thanks.

Comment: note that in Pascal it should be `shr`, `shr` and `or` instead